# DKIM not signing emails

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

I have set up DKIM key for signing email following this tutorial:
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mail/dkim-postfix-ubuntu/

DNS check with http://www.protodave.com/tools/dkim-key-checker/ is successful.

But when I check with check-auth2@verifier.port25.com if emails are signed, I get a softfail result

DomainKeys check - neutral (message not signed). According to doc "neutral" means:
 The message was signed but the signature or signatures
      contained syntax errors or were not otherwise able to be
      processed.  This result SHOULD also be used for other
      failures not covered elsewhere in this list.

I've spent hours searching for possible reasons but of no avail.

## Details:

## Summary of Results

SPF check:          softfail
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         neutral
Sender-ID check:    softfail
SpamAssassin check: ham

---

### DomainKeys check details:

Result:         neutral (message not signed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing **DKIM** and **DomainKeys** which are two different systems:

- DomainKeys: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys
- DKIM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail

Your summary does imply that neither of them is signing though.

Have you tried reading also other tutorials? Even if they are for a different platform, they may give you a better understanding of these systems.

Here is an Ansible automation script to set up Postfix with DKIM:

- https://github.com/sakaal/service_platform_ansible/blob/master/roles/postfix_standalone/tasks/main.yml

Make sure that you have read and understand all the configuration files:

- OpenDKIM documentation: http://www.opendkim.org/docs.html

I hope it helps!